# 74LS multiplexer outputing 2V as LOW

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm using a 74LS257 to select between 2 4-bit buses, but instead of 0V it's outputing 2V.

Here's the schematic:

[image: Schematic of the multiplexer]

The problem appears when Reading is logic 1 (selecting Actual). If Actual0 is logic 1, @0 outputs 2V. All the inputs are 0V or 5V (the problem lies in the IC's output). I have tried to replace it with another one, same results. The exact model is: SP8524 - DM74LS257BN.

All the outputs are conected to this RAM following this schematic:

[image: RAM conection]

Comment: That would not be the case for the *depicated* schematic, so something is being left out.  What load is it driving?  Is something else fighting it for the output?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the outputs @0, @1, @2 and @3 are connected just to the RAM. There's a lot of ICs in the circuit so I can't tell the load.

Comment: 1. Assuming no high voltage on your board, look for warm parts with your finger. Touch each briefly first so a really hot part won't burn you seriously. A part with a shorted output is often warmer than normal. 2. Probe around the board looking for the same 2V level. If you find the same level, this may be what you are shorted to.

Comment: Sounds like a short, or a defective/mismarked U20.  The most likely culprits for a short are solder bridges between the adjacent pins, or if it's just sitting on your bench, whatever little screw, washer, etc. you left underneath.

Comment: Until you can show the chip in *context* you don't have an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, @0 was connected to DB0 (and even worst, the RAM was not connected to GND). So silly for my part...